# Pass $_GET variable to the next page

Tags: php, pagination

Right now im trying to code read other codes and make it work, because some of the projects that i have are made by other developers and i really have to learn reading other code, I already made this one work but the problem is when i try to incorporate this pagination code to a $_GET variable an error occur, when it load the first page everything thing is smooth but when i click the other pages the $_GET variable dies. i already found a code in the site but i  can't really get how to incorporate it with the other code.

here is the code that "MIGHT" solve the problem [solving pagination $_GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13163232/passing-get-or-post-variables-with-pagination-session-not-working)

```
printf('<a href="%s?%s">Next</a>',$targetpage,http_build_query(array('page' => 2) + $_GET));
```

here is the part of the code that make the link 1 2 3 4. . . and so on

```
$range = 3;

// if not on page 1, don't show back links
if ($currentpage > 1) {
   // show << link to go back to page 1
   echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=1?srId=$srdd'><<</a> ";
   // get previous page num
   $prevpage = $currentpage - 1;
   // show < link to go back to 1 page
   echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$prevpage?srId=$srdd'><</a> ";
} // end if 

// loop to show links to range of pages around current page
for ($x = ($currentpage - $range); $x < (($currentpage + $range) + 1); $x++) {
   // if it's a valid page number...
   if (($x > 0) && ($x <= $totalpages)) {
      // if we're on current page...
      if ($x == $currentpage) {
         // 'highlight' it but don't make a link
         echo " [<b>$x</b>] ";
      // if not current page...
      } else {
         // make it a link
         echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$x?srId=$srdd'>$x</a> ";
      } // end else
   } // end if 
} // end for

// if not on last page, show forward and last page links        
if ($currentpage != $totalpages) {
   // get next page
   $nextpage = $currentpage + 1;
    // echo forward link for next page 
   echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$nextpage?srId=$srdd'>></a> ";
   // echo forward link for lastpage
   //echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$totalpages?srId=$srdd'>>></a> ";

   printf("<a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$totalpages?srId=$srdd'>>></a>");
} // end if
/****** end build pagination links ******/
?>
```

Comment: Take a look at sessions.

Comment: you mean the session variable? since a variable is being pass using the $_GET variable when you click the next link the $_GET variable becomes empty so as the $_SESSION variable i already studied its natures and actually already coded it, any other suggestions thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use either session variables or cookies to pass them one page to another.

The $_GET global array will be a NEW array for every new page, assuming you're sending a GET request and it can be seen in the URL.

In general, the web is stateless which means it will not remember what you do from one page to another UNLESS you use cookies, sessions or a database for persistence.

Design your links

```
Page 1 | 2 | 3 | 4
```

to have the information in the link so they are ready for the next page

```
Page 1 = http://url?page=1&page_limit=25 
Page 2 = http://url?page=2&page_limit=25 
...
Etc
```

If the paginated links are in this format, these variables will be in the $_GET array.

Comment: I think he mainly wants the URL to contain the GET values on the next page

Answer (score 0):

I already figured it out guys  I saw lots for this problem on the web and also some on the forum here's how to solve it

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    // store session data
    if (isset($_GET["srId"]))
    {   
        $_SESSION['variable']=$_GET["srId"];
        $srdd = $_SESSION['variable'];
    }
else
{
    $srdd = $_SESSION['variable'];
    $tableName = $srdd."r"; 
}   
    ?>
```

thanks for your response guys.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=1?srId=$srdd'><<</a> ";
```

with

```
echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=1&srId=$srdd'><<</a> ";
```

After the initial *'?'* in a url, the following *'$_GET[]'* items should be separated from the preceeding one with an *'&'*.  Note that your *'srId=$srdd'* is preceeded by a *'?'*.

Example:

myurl.com?id=1234&page=help

Doing it this way will help you avoid having to store the information in the $_SESSION array, and keeps the URL secure.

Comment: thanks @dismer, i also figured out another way to solve it with the use of isset.

Comment: Just a heads-up, this method will keep the data out of memory.